# prime prove: how to prove if $n! + n^2 + 1$ is prime then $n^2 + 1$ is also prime

Tags: prime-numbers

how to prove this:

> $$ \text{if } n! + n^2  + 1 \text{ is prime then } n^2  + 1 \text { is also prime}$$

I was thinking that n! is definitely not prime since it can be written as $n\times (n-1)....2\times 1$. So $n^2 + 1$ is not prime. In other words, n! does not have the same factor as $n^2 + 1$, and I don't know how to prove the following.

Comment: Suppose it is not.  Then  $n^2 + 1$ has a factor that is less than or equal to $n.$  But, if such a factor existed it would also divide $n!$ hence $n! + n^2 + 1$ could not be prime.

Comment: Suppose that $n!+n^2+1$ is prime.  Then in particular $2,3,4,5,\dots,n$ do not divide evenly into $n!+n^2+1$.  Clearly, though, each of $2,3,4,5,\dots,n$ divide evenly into $n!$.  What does this imply about whether or not any of $2,3,4,\dots,n$ divide evenly into $n^2+1$?  What possible candidates for factors of $n^2+1$ exist?

Comment: "*So $n^2+1$ is not prime*" $2^2+1=5$ is prime.  $4^2+1=17$ is prime.  Several other examples exist.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $n^2+1=uv$ is composite ($u,v$ proper factors).

As $n^2+1$ is not a square (being between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$), we have $u\ne v$, and without loss of generality assume $u\lt v$. Then $u\le n$ and, because $u\mid n^2+1$ and $u\mid n!$, we have $u\mid n!+n^2+1$ so $n!+n^2+1$ cannot be prime.